# Inconsistency between minimumBy and maximumBy

Tags: haskell

When `Data.List.minimumBy` comes across list elements that are equal, it chooses the one that came first, but `maximumBy` chooses the last one:

```
> import Data.List
> import Data.Ord
> minimumBy (const (const EQ)) "Hello world!"
'H'
> maximumBy (const (const EQ)) "Hello world!"
'!'
```

Is this by design or by coincidence? Is there a good reasoning behind this behavior?

Note that taking advantage of such an assumption can make code much more succinct - i.e `minimumOn length texts` instead of using an explicit tie-breaker such as `map snd (minimumOn (\(p, t) -> (length t, p)) (zip [0..] texts))`

Comment: The specifications of the functions do not mention anything in case of a *status quo*, so I think it is the freedom of the programmer to come up with a *tie breaker*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem true, however sometimes the code can be more succinct you use an assumption instead. i.e `minimumOn length texts` instead of the much more verbose `map snd (minimumOn (\(p, t) -> (length t, p)) (zip [0..] texts))`

Comment: I think it has a specific order to maintain the stability of any sorting algorithm that might be implemented based on these (or the underlying one).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the [Haskell report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1710009) there is a comment about min and max:

```
-- note that (min x y, max x y) = (x,y) or (y,x)  
    max x y  
         | x <= y    =  y  
         | otherwise =  x  
    min x y  
         | x <= y    =  x  
         | otherwise =  y
```

`minimumBy` and `maximumBy` are probably using these or at least trying to stay consistent with them.

I would guess the reason is that you might use min and max to, say, write a sort that involved comparing and swapping pairs (as in the operation in the comment above).  Without this property you could lose elements and have others duplicated.

You normally wouldn't be able to observe any difference, since things that compare equal are usually completely identical.  But you can imagine having elements with some sort of internal structure that isn't considered by comparisons but that you would not want to be lost during a sort.

Comment: I have to ask: did you happen to remember that comment somehow, or is there some other way you dug up that bit of trivia? That's an impressive find.

Comment: @dfeuer I didn't remember a specific reference but I must have heard at some point that min and max worked like that and I was fairly sure it was specified behaviour.  So I found it quickly by searching for min in the report.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from David Fletcher's point (and related to it), I'd reckon this behaviour is to preserve the invariant

```
minimum l ≡ head (sort l)
maximum l ≡ last (sort l)
```

also in its generalisation

```
minimumBy c l ≡ head (sortBy c l)
maximumBy c l ≡ last (sortBy c l)
```

...even if `c` behaves pathologically like your `const (const EQ)`. And because `sort` is stable, that means simply the list will be kept as-is, hence `minimum` should directly pick the `head` and `maximum` the `last` then.